# ERROR: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named

Tags: java, jpa, desktop-application

I'm new to JPA in Java. I followed a tutorial (I can't share it to public) step by step and the code runs successfully. But, when I run my code it shows:

> WARNING: jakarta.persistence.spi::No valid providers found.

I asked many experts in the field but no one found a solution.

I tried all solutions like adding the hibernate-core.jar and many other solutions for this error mentioned in Stack Overflow.
I'm not using maven, like the tutorial I followed did! Here is my persistence.xml file the same as the tutorial:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Prog3Assi3PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>Ch5Apps.Department</class>
        <class>Ch5Apps.Employee</class>
        <class>Ch5Apps.EmployeeProjects</class>
        <class>Ch5Apps.Project</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/companyjpa?serverTimezone=UTC"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I'm sure that port number of the localhost is correct, and the persistence.xml is in the right path. I tried using *javax.persistence* and the same error appears.
Please note: I'm using NetBeans 17, JDK 20 and tried JDK 17 but the problem still appears.